# terminal dosnt install discord?

Tags: elementary-project

I am a new user in elementary os. I tried installing a deb file in the terminal, however it doesn't work. I had tried `sudo apt install` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

To install a downloaded .deb file, you have to use the command **dpkg**.

```
sudo dpkg -i <distination>/<package>.deb
```

Or install **Eddy**, it's point and click for .deb files.

By the way Discord is available at Flathub: [enter link description here](https://flathub.org/apps/search/discord)

Answer (score 1):

- Download [discord](https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb), then install `sudo dpkg -i discord-*.deb`.

or

- Easy way just install discord from flatpak `flatpak install flathub com.discordapp.Discord` or you can browse/ search in Appcenter

Comment: DO NOT use `sudo` to install Flatpak applications

Comment: @Borislav, sorry.. my bad :(